# PHP empty session files generated

Tags: php, session, session-cookies

I have a site where I use session authorization for my users
Details are:

```
PHP Version 7.2.8
session.gc_maxlifetime  604800
session.gc_probability  1
session.gc_divisor  1000
```

I use the following db.php file for creating a session

```
$dinamo_session = session_name("dinamo_session");
ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.DOMAIN_NAME'); 

#if (isset($_REQUEST[session_name("dinamo_session")])) {
    #ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', 604800);
    #ini_set('session.gc-maxlifetime', 604800);
    #ini_set('session.save_path', '/var/www/user9357/data/_SESSIONS');
    session_start();
    #session_regenerate_id(true);
    #session_write_close();
#}
```

My users do not complain from their end everything seems to be ok, the only thing is that I see a growing amount of session files with zero sizes (as well as I see normal session files with the real session's data)
You can see different lines of code are commented out. I tried to use all of them to avoid creation of these zero size files but that did not help (isset - to check if the session has been created before, session_regenerate_id(true) - to delete the old files) but no luck. I even had to comment out isset as some users complained that they were not able to log in. I also checked that: Opera and Firefox were ok, but Vivaldi browser was not able to login

Any ideas why these zero files are created and how can I stop it?

Comment: Are you perhaps not writing anything to those sessions? Is the cookie_domain definitely correct?

Comment: Hi Jon. I do write something in the session files as there are hundreds of them with real session information. And all users successfully authorized there. The domain name is not real, I just replaced it in code with .DOMAIN_NAME to paste info here. The only thing I can think of, is that I use RedBeanPHP (ORM for PHP) to create and select users but I do not know how it can influence on creating empty session files. I wonder is there a real way to find the reason of creation these empty zero files?

Comment: What if, say, somebody simply drops onto your homepage or similar, and then leaves. They get a session, do they get any data? You say other sessions are working fine, so I'm reluctant to say that some random sessions are just not working.

Comment: I tried to use isset function
'if (isset($_REQUEST[session_name("dinamo_session")])) {'
to start sessions only when it's been created previously - did not help. Zero files continued created

Comment: OK, I played with a logic of my files and I hope I will find the reason of these empty files
The only thing that I do not understand is that when I want to delete a session I use following code

`$dinamo_session = session_name("dinamo_session");
session_start();
session_destroy();
$_SESSION = array();`

And I do not understand why I still see in my console existing session cookie and I see an empty file. And when I login again I see that the old file (that used to be zero size) again is filled with data. Is there a way to delete the session file together with the cookie?

Comment: Anyway, now I see that the number of the session files is stable, and does not grow everyday (probably old files are deleted by Garbage Collector correctly)
Thanks for the help, and I will continue thinking about correct architecture of web my application )